# Is it possible to create a "perfect forwarding" generic collection in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c++11

Consider this C++ code snippet:

```
std::vector<Foo> bar;
bar.emplace_back(9001);    //Foo defines a constructor that takes int
```

This will create an object of type `Foo`, pass-through any constructor arguments, and store the new object in the vector. Functionally equivalent to `bar.push_back(Foo(9001));`, but more efficient, since no temporary `Foo` is created.

**Is there a way to implement similar functionality in C#?**

If so, would it provide any real benefit, like in C++, or would it only be *syntactic sugar*?

**EDIT**: The question is specifically regarding a collection of value types in C# (structs); the benefit I am looking for (besides simplified `Add` syntax) is similar to that of C++11 `emplace`methods - no need to construct, copy, and destroy (GC) a temporary object.

Comment: Please note that C# lists take a pointer to object and there's no expensive copy involved.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, what if the object being stored is a `struct`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here. C# does not have the kind of syntax to support some arbitrary parameter list being forwarded to a constructor. You have to know ahead of time what needs to be passed. But other than that, yes...as long as the type is a value type (i.e. `struct`), "constructing" a type simply fills in the allocated memory location in-place, without a temporary object being created. If this memory location is an element of the array backing a collection, that's where it goes.

Comment: If it's not a `struct`, then the object only has to be allocated once anyway. It's a reference to the object that would be stored. At best, your "is there a way..." question is too broad, and when you ask "would it provide any real benefit..." you get into "unclear" territory, because it's not obvious what you would consider a "real benefit".

Comment: (I will note that you could use reflection to deal with a dynamic parameter list, but that will result in the boxing of any value type involved, so would not satisfy the "emplace" requirement.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I considered reflection, but issue is boxing, as you mentioned. I understand there is no benefit to reference types - I will clarify my question - it's specifically regarding value types stored in a collection. Real benefit would be similar to that of C++ `emplace` - it saves an allocation, a copy, and a destruction of a temporary object.

Comment: @PeterDuniho per your first comment - *"constructing" a type simply fills in the allocated memory location in-place, without a temporary object being created. If this memory location is an element of the array backing a collection, that's where it goes.* - are you saying, for instance, that `new List<Point>().Add(new Point(1,2))` in C# works similar to `emplace` methods in C++? That is, only a single allocation of `Point` struct takes place?

Comment: No, that example passes the new value to the `Add()` method first, so it can't go directly into the array. The parameter is on the stack, so allocation is basically free. But there is the extra copy. You would have to assign something like `array[index] = new Point(1, 2);`. I.e. the type/method holding the array would have to know about the parameters and construct the type directly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, that's what I thought - and the extra object allocated (near zero cost) has to be GC'd (not zero cost; especially in a game, for instance, where GC can cause lag) - hence my question. I thought there's gotta be a way...

Comment: Have you considered that a `struct` **always** have a default constructor that does **nothing**? Hence, you can forget its constructor, and just let the container allocate it and fill it in-place with no copies with your own method or setters afterwards.

Comment: _"the extra object allocated (near zero cost) has to be GC'd"_ -- that's not true. Value types are only put on the heap as individual objects if they wind up boxed. Which it wouldn't if all you're doing is passing to the `Add()` method. That's why I wrote _"The parameter is on the stack"_.

Comment: I will also point out that parameters to methods are values too. So you seem to be asking for the ability to avoid creating a single value (i.e. an instance of a value type), so that you can instead pass several values to the method instead. This hardly seems like a genuine win. At best, a microoptimization that will never have any benefit at all, and at worst you're passing the data _less_ efficiently than you could have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it's.. cumbersome.

In .Net, structs are *always* copied around. Any attempt to pass a struct in any way will result in a copy:

```
SuperList x;
x.Add(new MyStruct());
```

More over, this one will actually probably create at least 3 instances:

- one which you created
- copy passed into Add method
- copy inside the list data store that the Add method will write to

You can now remove some of that by using factory

```
SuperList x;
x.Add(() => new MyStruct());
```

but then:

- you got one created by factory
- and copy inside the list data store that the factory will write to

So.. if you attempt to pass the new instance into the store in any way, it will be copied.

The only way I can think of that does not involve making any copies is to allow the store to create it for you. The most simple example is..:

```
SuperList x;
x.AddNewItems(1);
```

Nevermind how the store implements it. Let's say it is smart enough to not do any copies. For example, it can use a sort of LinkedList<> and just append a new node.

This way, by asking the store to create an object for you, the store **has a chance** of just creating the item. It has to be implemented properly of course, but that's another topic. New item will probably be created with all-defaults, unless you elaborate the `CreateItem` with more parameters and some specific logic, but .. let's say that creating it with defaults is OK.

What now? Now, of course, there's problem working (i.e. reading, modifying, etc) that item:

```
class SuperList
{
    MyStruct GetItem(int id);
}
```

Well, that obviously will return a copy. Oops.

If you are using C# 7.0 you can use ref variables, maybe, I have not ever tried yet:

```
class SuperList
{
    ref MyStruct GetItem(int idx);
}

ref MyStruct aRef = x.GetItem(x.Count-1);
aRef.Name = "mom";
```

but unless it's C#7, you can't and have to work it around a long way:

```
class SuperList
{
    delegate void ItemAccessor(ref MyStruct y); // <- REF! no copy
    void WorkWithItem(int idx, ItemAccessor func);
}

x.WorkWithItem(1, (ref MyStruct it) => {
    it.Name="mom";
});
```

Finally, since we can create a **store** and can access its items in some way, you can do anything you want to wrap it in porcelain layers to provide whatever user frontend to create and initialize those objects. For example, you can create a API with "constructor' method:

```
var x = new SuperList<T,U,...>( (ref item, T t, U u, ..) => {
    item.First = t;
    item.Second = u;
    ...
});

x.CreateItem(new T(), new U(), ...);
```

or do it via `object[] args` and Reflection. Whatever. It will be cumbersome to use, or to implement, or both of that, I would think many times about going this way. `class` is much more convenient to work with than `struct`. But all of that is certainly possible if really needed.

Ah yes, and the second part of the question:

> If so, would it provide any real benefit, like in C++, or would it only be syntactic sugar?

Why, of course, by definition the benefit would be: not making copies. This means that if the objects **are large** you will get performance benefit, obvious one, assuming that **copying** takes **significant time**.

On the other side, if the objects are small, you will get a performance hit due to passing the `ref` pointers, extra deferences, calling methods, creating delegate instances, and so on. For small-sized structs, it may turn out that the infrastructure you built simply takes more time (not space!) to invoke than simply copying that struct forth-and-back. This is something you should consider when aiming for such optimisation.

I actually don't know how large a structure would need to be to get a benefit. Copying structures is fast, they were desinged for it. It actually is almost raw byte-by-byte copy, which the processor can do **really fast**.

I remember many performance tests regarding accessing, GC'inc, copying, etc of value types and reference types. Search on the internet, and be sure to read the code they measured, because there are a lot of errors that can skew the results. Anyways, for copying `structs` it is all about their byte-size and speed of copying blocks of memory.

So.. to have a large structure.. to make our SmartList worthwhile. What to put inside the struct? a huge array of data? nope, the struct will be small, and it will keep a reference to large array:

```
struct X { public int[] f; }
static void Main()
{
    X a;a.f = new []{5};
    X b;b = a;
    a.f[0]=4;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + b.f[0]); // FOUR!
}
```

If a `int[]` inside a `struct` is actually a reference, then **almost anything** you keep in the struct will often be a small reference that has a small footprint. You'd need a `struct` that has a **large** amount of fields and/or most of those fields would need to be a **heavy non-array value-types** themselves.. that's not something you see often. It's just too easy to break out the 'large value-type' idea and make the struct broken into referenced pieces, as you see on that `int[]` example.